# In Linux what setup would allow striping data across multiple drives?

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, raid, software-raid

How would a system be set up to stripe data like raid does, preferably with out using raid. Could lvm be used for this?

Comment: Since you want a RAID feature, why don't you want to use RAID?

Comment: @Gilles This is entirely theoretical. I am just interested in the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up lvm will get you a RAID 0-like striped configuration if you set it up with multiple devices.  That's the whole idea of lvm, it is an abstraction of the physical devices, treating them all as one device.  You only need to use `--stripes` if you are creating a RAID 4/5/6, as RAID 0 goes without saying. `--mirrors` will get you the equivalent of a RAID 1.

Answer (score 1):

LVM can do that, indeed. You can use `lvconvert` to convert a linear volume into a mirror volume and you can use `lvcreate --mirrors` to create a mirror volume.

I guess that LVM's (or rather: the device mapper's) mirror target uses the MD (softRAID) code internally but that probably isn't a problem for you.

Comment: Since he said `stripes`, he probably wants `--stripes`.

Comment: @jordanm ``--stripes`` is unnecessary for simple (RAID 0) striping, it's simply what you  normally get when you set up an LVM across multiple volumes. @Hauke Laging ``--mirrors`` will get exactly what OP doesn't want